# ViewModel that automagically has same properties than generic model

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, .net-4.6

I'm trying to create code for the use-case in the code below, where a generic ViewModel class "captures" all the properties from its model, and presents properties with the same name and type, and also triggers `PropertyChanged` event for data-binding.

Is there a way to do it? I'm using .NET 4.6.

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public double Width {get; set;}
    public double Height {get; set;}
}

public class RectangleViewModel : MagicViewModel<Rectangle>
{
    public RectangleViewModel(Rectangle model) 
        : base(model){ }
}

public class MagicViewModel<TModel> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected readonly TModel _model;

    public MagicViewModel(TModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    // inpc implementation

    // what else?
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vm = new RectangleViewModel(new Rectangle());
        var calls = 0;
        vm.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => calls++;
        vm.Height = 10;  // magic happened here
        Debug.Assert(calls > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to automatically inject code that raises the `PropertyChanged` event for all properties of the model classes at *compile* time.

Then you could bind directly to `Rectangle` without modify it and explicitly implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Othwerwise I am afraid that you will have to define each property, one-by-one, in each view model or come up with a way to auto-generate the view model classes before you build.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Rectangle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double height;

    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get => height; set => SetField(ref height, value); }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}

public class RectangleViewModel : MagicViewModel<Rectangle>
{
    public RectangleViewModel(Rectangle model)
        : base(model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    private Rectangle model;

    public Rectangle Model { get => model; set => SetField(ref model, value); }
}

public class MagicViewModel<TModel> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected readonly TModel _model;

    public MagicViewModel(TModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vm = new RectangleViewModel(new Rectangle());
        var calls = 0;
        vm.PropertyChanged += (sender, propChangedArgs) => calls++;
        vm.Model.Height = 10;  // magic happened here
        Debug.Assert(calls > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well not quite. I need the Model to be any class or even struct with public get/set properties. Your suggestion requires the model to (re)implement a lot of infrastructure that you used in your MagicViewModel implementation, eliminating any of the duplication removal benefit that was the main goal in the first place. For example, a Model that implements INPC surely should not be required.

Comment: Unless you're using something like PostSharp or Fody (like mm8 mentioned) you kinda do have to implement INPC at each level.  Otherwise there's nothing to raise the PropertyChanged event.  You can inherit from a base class that has the actual INPC implementation, but your setters would still need to call Set(ref yourField, value).

Comment: Currently what I do is to implement INPC in ViewModel, and the Model classes have only auto-properties, with simple get/set methods. The problem is that I have to write, in the ViewModel, a property and an INPC get/set pair for each property in the model, and their types end up being strongly coupled. I'll take a closer look at Fody, I see it being mentioned often for this use case. Thanks!